# Updates available show both virtualbox-guest-dkms and virtualbox-guest-x11

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Elementary 0.4.1 inside Virtualbox. Updates available show both virtualbox-guest-dkms and virtualbox-guest-x11
What is the difference? Which one(s) should I install/update?

### Thanks!